# How to have TabbedContainer and SingleContainer within the same stack?

Tags: exrin

I would like to provide a drawer for navigation. There are TabbedContainer pages  (for example the home or main page) and also there are SingleContainer pages.

Currently I have to switch stack to trigger calling of SetStack in IMasterDetailView which will change the Details page. However this way the navigation is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about changing the Stack on the DetailPage, from a MasterPage navigation link, the best way to do this is with the container and region mapping.

In your TabbedViewContainer, in the constructor, label your Master and Detail pages, as such.

```
RegionMapping.Add("Master", ContainerType.Master);
RegionMapping.Add("Detail", ContainerType.Detail);
```

Next, also note the name you assigned your container, e.g.

```
public TabbedViewContainer(MainStack mainStack, SecondStack secondStack)
        : base(Containers.Tabbed.ToString(), null)
```

Then when you do a navigate, make sure you specify the Container and Region, in this case `Containers.Tabbed.ToString()` and `"Detail"`, and it will cause the navigation in that particular region.

Comment: Adam, many thanks for the answer. I am going to check, just overwhelmed a bit, I have much more question/problem to solve, but do not want to flood SO (and you). I'll be back a few hours later, or weekend with feedback

Comment: Talking about ExrinSampleMobileApp: I do not want to navigate out from MainContainer, because MainContainer implements the drawer menu via the Xam built in MasterDetailPage. If I navigate out, from that container, then the drawer disappears. I understand the region concept inside, so I concluded I also have to navigate in Regions.Main. Initially the TabbedContainer shows there. From the menu I want to navigate to say a Settings page, but do not want to show the settings page within a tabbed page instead I want to see it in solo. The only way to do this to force SetStack be called...